# Passing a swift class to objective c with segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have my VC1 that has this:

```
if segue.identifier == "toAccountSummary" {
    let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DynamicSummaryTableViewController
    secondViewController.firstname1 = self.account.firstName1

}
```

plus:

VC2.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *firstname1;
```

and it passes the string from swift to objective C just fine. But what I want to do is pass a whole class that contains variables.

my class looks like this in swift:

```
class Account {

    var firstName1 = ""
    var lastName1 = ""
    var accountNumber = ""
    var address1 = ""
    var address2 = ""
    var city = ""
...
}
```

I just dont know how to accept this on the objective C side and for example, print

```
Account.address1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subclass `NSObject` for Objective-C to work with Swift.

```
class Account: NSObject {
    var firstName1 = ""
    var lastName1 = ""
    var accountNumber = ""
    var address1 = ""
    var address2 = ""
    var city = ""
}
```

In your Objective-C file, you also want to import the swift header, like so:

```
#import "project-swift.h"
```

where "project" is the name of your project.

Comment: you also want to import the swift header, which is called <project name>-swift.h. I've updated the answer.

Comment: what should the property look like though on objective c

Comment: like you would normally access class variables

Comment: You could also give your class the `objc` attribute (which is actually what happens when you derive from `NSObject`). So you could say `@objc class Account { ... }`. See the Swift Programming Language iBook, around page 855.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `@objc` is just ensuring objective-c comparability by not messing up the class name. I have very few `@objc` tags in my shared code.